# Material design lite masonry layout with cards

Tags: masonry, material-design-lite

I'm trying to create a "Pinterest" style layout with Material Design Lite. The big issue is that so far, I'm only able to create it with the cards being the same height.

I have been able to do it with CSS and column count (without MDL), but I'd like to use the styling MDL provides. If I use column-count with MDL, it cause some weird layout. My cards vary in size, and it looks bad when they have huge gaps inside them because the gridlayout evens them out in height. I hope it makes sense. I can paste my Wordpress theme code if necessary, but I'm not sure if it's to any help.

I hope someone can help me out :-)

Comment: Yes, you need to paste your codes, errors here. Then fellow programmers can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this lightweight javascript http://masonry.desandro.com/ in order to do that. use it like this.

```
<div class="mdl-grid masonry-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-desktop masonry-grid-item">
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col-desktop masonry-grid-item">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var elem = document.querySelector('.masonry-grid');
    var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
     // options
     itemSelector: '.masonry-grid-item'
    });
</script>
```